# Getting highest values from Firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a game in JavaScript. I want to save scores(with names of the players) in Firebase Databse. Here is the structure of my database, but it can be modified if it is needed:

[image: My database].

How can I get and save to an array i.e. 3 of the best scores and belonging to them names?
Here is part of my code where I am saving the scores and trying to get them:

```
function writeUserData(name, score) {
    firebase.database().ref("scores/").push({
        name: name,
        score: score,
    });
}

var bestScores = {};

var scoresRef = database.ref("scores");
scoresRef.orderByValue().limitToLast(3).on("value", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
      bestScores[data.key] = data.val();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ordering the nodes under `scores` based on the value of a child property, so in that case you need to use `orderByChild` and not `orderByValue`.

```
var scoresRef = database.ref("scores");
scoresRef.orderByChild("score").limitToLast(3).on("value", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
      console.log(data.key); // "-M-...."
      console.log(data.val().name); // "Anrzej"
      console.log(data.val().score); // 11
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But now I am getting values of childes like "M-zebBLvDrOIYwY1WAn". What I need to do next to get names and scores?

Comment: I added some more info on that, but I highly recommend studying the Firebase documentation and maybe a tutorial, as getting values from snapshots is covered in a lot of places already.